# Adding a command to the IBM Lotus Notes 9 mail popup only, using a plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, lotus-notes, rcp

I need to make a menu contribution to IBM Lotus Notes 9 Mails with the following requirements:

- View: Show the menu entry in the popup menu and there inside the submenu which has the label equal to the sender of the email
- Mail detail: show in the popup menu as 'normal'
- Only show the menu entry if the user selected a mail inside the mailbox view OR if the user is in an open mail

At the moment, I used

```
<menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=additions">
```

so, the menu entry is shown in every popup menu.
I searched the web but couldn't find the ids for the popup menu extension point and for the visibleWhen check.

Which locationURI should I use to add the menu entry as I need it?
Which visibleWhen rule shoud I use?
Is there any documentation available listing the ids of the extension points in Notes 9?